# Sublime Text: word wrap toggle from menu disabling syntax specific settings

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

**How do I return to a world where the User customized syntax specific settings are controlling the word wrap?**

Sublime Text 3, Max OSX El Capitan.

Here is my User settings file:

```
# User/Shell-Unix-Generic.sublime-settings

"extensions":
  [
    "sh"
  ],
  "word_wrap": true,
  "wrap_width": 140
}
```

Recently, word wrap was working as expected. Then I started using the menu item **Word Wrap: Toggle** from the command palette. It toggles wrap on and off, to the default setting (80) on the menu item.

I don't want this toggling behavior any more.

#### *notes*

[I found this old sublime text forum](https://sublimetext.userecho.com/forums/1-general/topics/3179-syntax-specific-word_wrap-setting-is-ignored/) where Jon Skinner says the toggling behavior overrides the settings by design. No word about how to return to the user settings behavior.

Restarting sublime restored the user settings wrap behavior, but "restart sublime and don't use the wrap menu item any more" is not a satisfying solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `Word Wrap: Toggle` item from the Command Palette uses the `toggle_setting` command. This sets the preference directly on the view, which indeed overrides any default, user or syntax specific preferences.

You can return to the user/syntax specific settings behavior by closing and reopening any files where the `Word Wrap: Toggle` item from the Command Palette was used, as the view specific settings will be lost when the file is closed.
Alternatively, you could achieve the same thing without closing any files by opening the ST Python console (View menu -> Show Console) and typing `view.settings().erase('word_wrap')` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will clear the view-specific setting for the active tab.

You could also get it to clear the setting from all open views in the current window at once, using `[view.settings().erase('word_wrap') for view in window.views()]` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This is an improvement on restarting sublime, I will test it out. The console commands are especially helpful, can you post an update on creating a palette command for this? Closing/reopening a file to reset a setting is not an acceptable workflow.